# UILocalNotification repeatInterval on 20 days

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'd like to create local notification with **custom interval repeat** (every 20 days for example).
I know we have NSDayCalendarUnit, kCFCalendarUnitMonth ... but I hope to set repeat interval at 20 days.
I don't want to create a notification for every day.

My real need is to repeat a notification for consecutive 21 days, then don't launch it for 7 days later, then a new 21 days with notification and 7 days without ... etc. 
I should schedule all these days even if application is inactive.

To do this I decide to create a 21 notifications since a fire date with repeatInterval = 28days (here is the problem)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you can change the intervall by selecting `setDay`, `setMonth`, .... :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:3];

NSDate *date3Days = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components 
                                               toDate:[NSDate date] 
                                              options:0];

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray*    oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
if ( oldNotifications ) {
    [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlarm) {
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = date3Days;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = NSLocalizedString( @"Push message", @"");
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"sound.wav";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

---

If you want to set a specific time after which the `UILocalNotifications` should appear you can create a method of the above solution and loop over an array which indicates the days you like to show a notification:

```
NSArray *arrayNumbers = @[@5, @7, @14, @21, @30, @60, @90, @120];
NSDictionary *dictNotifications = 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    objectForKey:kUserDefAppStarts];

for ( NSNumber *bla in arrayNumbers ){

    NSString *strKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kUserDefAppStarts, bla];
    NSDictionary *dict = dictNotifications[strKey];
    NSString *strMessageQuestion = dict[kKeyMessage];

    [self createNotificationWithNumberOfDays:[bla integerValue]
                                  andMessage:strMessageQuestion
                                    userInfo:dict];
}
```

And here is the method you have to call

```
+ (void)createNotificationWithNumberOfDays:(int)days 
                                andMessage:(NSString *)message 
                                  userInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict{

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:days];

NSDate *dateAlert = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if( notifyAlarm ){
    [notifyAlarm setFireDate:dateAlert];
    [notifyAlarm setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [notifyAlarm setSoundName:@"soundname"];
    [notifyAlarm setAlertBody:message];
    [notifyAlarm setUserInfo:dict];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
}
```

}

Comment: Yup, was just about to say this.

Comment: Is it the answer to your question? Than don't forget to mark it as correct so people know which one is the correct answer.

Comment: It simple to do this. But I would like to create only one notification that launch a notification every 20 days.

Comment: I have tested a solution like this but it doesn't work when app is not active !!

Comment: The app has to be opened once to set a `UILocalNotification`. There is no other way to create notifications. Even for remote notifications the user has to open the app once and agree with the pop up. Whats exactly your problem?

Comment: Your solution supposed that i launch the app at every receive of notification

Comment: My real need is to repeat a notification for consecutives 21 days, then don't launch it for 7 days later, then a new 21 days with notification and 7 days without ... etc.

I should schedule all these days even if application is inactive

Comment: I gave you a possibility to create a single UINotification. If you implement this into a method you can loop over it to set a set of days you like to show your notifications, i edited my post, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to schedule a UILocalNotification for 20 days in the future from the current time you would do this:

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
int desiredAmountOfMonths = 4;
for (int month = 0; month < desiredAmountOfMonths; month++)
{
    dateComp.month = month;
    dateComp.day = 20;
    NSDate *fireDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComp toDate:[NSDate date] options:NSCalendarMatchNextTimePreservingSmallerUnits];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
}
```

You will need to modify the UILocalNotification for what message, sound, etc and then fire the notification once done customizing.

Comment: You can't use 86400 for one day.

Comment: Is that not the number of seconds in a solar day? Or could you explain why you could not use that?

Comment: Days are not always 86,400 seconds long. You should use the NSCalendar functions to calculate time periods.

Comment: I would like to create only one notification that is launched every 20 days (for exemple a notification in 20/12, 10/01, 30/01, 20/02 ...)

Comment: Updated my code. You would need to make a for loop and then increase the month by one.

Comment: It simple to do this. But I would like to create only one notification that launch a notification every 20 days.

Comment: So you want to schedule a notification for 20 days into the future and once that notification is received, schedule another one for 20 days if certain conditions are not met?

Comment: @dev_marou local notifications like this do not repeat.