# How to notify UILocalNotification for every two week

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications, localnotification

Good Morning,
How to notify localNotification for every two weeks (14days) a notification.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60*24*14 target:self selector:@selector(getNotifiedForTwoWeeks:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

-(void)getNotifiedForTwoWeeks:(id)userinfo{

        // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate =  [NSDate date];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Notification Message";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Please let me know is this implementation is correct or not?
Is there any alternative way i can do the best for notifying a LocalNotification message for every two weeks.

Your valuable inputs are appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what this `NSTimer` is for, as that's only going to work if the app is active for 2 weeks. You should update the `fireDate` to be some date in the future (and you should perform `NSCalendar` calandrical calculations rather than 60*60*24*12). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27424355/1271826.

Comment: If it were every week or every month, rather than every two weeks, you could use `repeatInterval`, but for every two weeks, I think you have to schedule them yourself, as shown in that answer.

Comment: @NSTimer is used to schedule for TimeInterval to trigger the specific method for given notification declared method.

Answer (score 0):

When your app will enter to background the system will suspend it after some time and your `NSTimer` will not schedule. 
So you can schedule for every 14 days notification through declare a `fireDate` and `repeatInterval` properties in `UILocalNotification`

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate =  [NSDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*14];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Notification Message";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: Needless to say, `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` is useless when it comes to a timer scheduled for 60*60*24*14. The whole timer thing is dead end for this use case, anyway. It's good for a few minutes, not a few weeks.

Comment: Yeah you are right